# How can I create a color image (RGB), after changing it into a 3 dimensional array of each pixel?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

My issue is that I'm taking a sample image and trying to change specific RGB values to change the appearance. After getting the data for each pixel, saving it as a 3-dimensional array, I then try to turn it back into an image but I'm getting the following error.

[image]

I know that it wants 2-dimensional arrays to convert it back into an image, but I don't know how i can keep it in color and convert it back to an image. Any ideas?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Opens the image, giving it the call name im
img = Image.open("sample_images\sample_image_1.jpg")

# This function makes a list containing every RGB value of each pixel in sample_image_1
img_as_list = np.uint8(np.asarray(img))
print(img_as_list)

for x in img_as_list:
    for rVal in x[0]:
        if rVal <= 255:
            rVal = 0

    for bVal in x[1]:
        if bVal <= 255:
            bVal = 0

    for gVal in x[2]:
        if gVal <= 255:
            gVal = 0

# Crate a new image from the list that i made from the picture
new_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img_as_list),"L")
print(img_as_list)

new_img.show()
img.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: add error as text, not as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is luckily quite simple.

instead of

```
new_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img_as_list),"L")
```

use

```
new_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img_as_list))
```

The `L` means that it is expecting 8-bit pixels, black and white. So it would only need a 0-255 value for each pixel. Instead use another mode.

Instead of removing the parameter completely, you could instead use `RGB` or `RGBA` depending on the file type.

Check out [this](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes) out for more modes.

Hope this helps!